# GD::Graph::lines: how to plot axis as whole numbers only?

Tags: perl, graph, gd

I'm making graphs with [GD::Graph](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph) and want the y-axis to display as whole numbers, not with decimals. The axis auto generates based on data (from a scale under a beehive). I'm stumped.

Here's a sample plot:

[image]

My graph parameters are:

```
 $graph->set(                                           #set the graph parameters
 two_axes        => 2,
 zero_axis       => 0,
 title           => "$hostname $location - $altitude feet elev.      Hive Weight and Temp $weight_filter       $date",
 use_axis        => [1,2,2],
 line_width      => 3,
 x_label         => 'Time',
 x_ticks         => 1,
 x_long_ticks    => 1,
 y_long_ticks    => 1,
 x_tick_number   => $number_of_days+$number_of_days,
 x_number_format => sub { time2str( "%D", $_[0] ) },
 x_label_skip    =>   2,
 y1_label        => 'Weight (Pounds)',
 y2_label        => 'Temperature (Fahrenheit)',
 y1_min_value    =>  int $min_weight,
 y1_max_value    =>  int ($max_weight+1),
 x_min_value     =>  $first_date,
 x_max_value     =>  $last_date,
 y2_min_value    =>  int $min_y2,
 y2_max_value    =>  int ($max_y2+1),
 transparent     => 0,
 boxclr          => 'lgray',
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust `y_tick_number`. But note that if you want the ticks for both `y1` and `y2` to be at integer values then you need to adjust everything so that the number of ticks evenly divides both ranges. You may also want to set `y_number_format => '%.0f'` to remove the `.0` on the integer numbers.